# Complement of a Language which is set of Turing Machine descriptions

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, closure-properties

If $L$ is the set of strings $\langle M\rangle$ such that $M$ accepts all strings of even length and does not accept any strings of odd length.

What will be  $\overline L$ ?

a) set of strings $\langle M\rangle$ such that $M$ accepts all strings of even length as well as any strings of odd length.

b) set of strings $\langle M\rangle$ such that $M$ accepts all strings of odd length and does not accept any strings of even length.

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help.  Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the tip. But I found the question very straight forward, i.e. Finding the complement of set. And I have given what I think the answers could be (This is what I tried), see the options a and b. And it is not an exercise It was actually a doubt that arose while solving another problem.

Comment: It's usually more helpful to provide your reasoning, rather than just your guess at the answer, so we can see what you are thinking -- and even more helpful to use the exercise to help you identify what you are confused about and then ask a question about whatever concept is not clear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. A machine $M$ is not in $L$ if either it rejects some even-length string or it accepts some odd-length string (or both).